# Socket error messages change between Ubuntu 14.04 and 18.04 when connecting to a server with a wrong host name

Tags: python, sockets, ubuntu-14.04, ubuntu-18.04

I am working with a Daemon server running on Ubuntu 14.04. I have written a test where I try to connect to it with a wrong host name and I am capturing the server error message which is :

***socket.gaierror: [Errno -5] No address associated with hostname***

However, I am transitioning to Ubuntu 18.04. I am expecting this test to work but it seems that the error message has changed to :

***socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known***

Is it a change in the socket module mechanism on Ubuntu 14.04 vs Ubuntu 18.04?

And if yes, where could I find the documentation (I looked on the Net bu didn't find anything)?

And if no, what could cause this divergence in the error massage given by the socket module when trying to connect with a wrong host name?

Thank you for taking the time to read.

Comment: Is it the same Python versions?

Comment: Yes, both servers use : `Python 2.7.14 :: Anaconda custom (64-bit)`

Comment: looks like different errno was returned by syscall, in other words, change happens outside python , closer to OS level.

Answer (score 1):

There have been very many bug fixes to glibc concerning error codes from `getaddrinfo` (the underlying system call associated with these name lookups), so it's entirely possible this could have changed somewhere or other.

For example [this one](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=7080), although old, looks very possibly relevant.  The patch proposed there has it returning `EAI_NONAME` (which corresponds with the newer message you're getting "Name or service not known") when it wasn't returning it in that case before.  It's probably not the specific one that caused the change you're seeing, but it's just an example of something that might have.

It could be something like this, or a similar change--you can search the above-linked bugzilla database for other if you're really unsure.  Depending on your use case it would probably in most cases suffice to treat both errors equivalently.